# need to run service while device got wifi/data connection

Tags: android, service, android-wifi

Last time, I use following coding to run background service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(InitActivity.this, GetService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(InitActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);                
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 50 * 1000, pintent);
return getZipInfo.toString();
```

to make better performance, I want to run my background service once device is connect WIFI/data connection. To make clear, if device is not connect wifi/data connection, my background service will not run for sure. Once connect wifi/data connection, it will run immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check the WiFi connection you can use

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
// Do whatever
}
```

To execute the code whenever the Wifi is connected, you have to use `Broadcast Receiver`

Register the receiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In your Receiver class do this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
final String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        // wifi connection was lost
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add below permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Where should Receiver  be registered?  Please explain

Comment: @Nbn, receiver should be registered on startup of your launcher activity