# A good strategy for checking connection?

Tags: android, connection

In my project, I have 6 activities and 4 fragments. Just 1 of them is not using internet connection. All the buttons, social network api's bla bla bla using internet. So, if we count, at least 60 lines of code can give fatal error if there is no connection.

Using a checkConnection method *for all these lines* sounds bad for me. So, the question is; how and where should I use this connection checker? Anyone has a good strategy?

EDIT: My connection checker is very simple. Just checks when its called and if there is no connection; says "no connection" and returns previous activity.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063910/need-to-run-service-while-device-got-wifi-data-connection/17064006#17064006

Comment: @JibranKhan I couldn't get where should I use these lines. IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

and found nothing to write over broadcastReceiver...

Comment: Place this code in the receiver onRecieve event.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedToWIFI(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Aah. There should be a misunderstanding. I have the code to check connection. I need a strategy to use it efficiently.

Comment: You can Use the given methods in the doInBackground() of an ASYNCTASK whenever you are trying to fetch any value depending on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a wrapper method for any web base endpoint and write this code once there, the method should return a Boolean or an Enum value to the UI for you to handle these situations and tell the user what is wrong if something is (like no connection, low connection etc..)